# Javascript new Image() memory management

Tags: javascript

Example code:

```
var image1 = new Image();
var image2 = new Image();

image1.src = "some_image.png";
image2.src = "some_image.png";
```

Is some_image.png loaded in memory twice, or just once?

Comment: Highly depends on the browser, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to test it, without any precise memory profiling tools and ignoring the fact it is actually depends on implementation, is following - try to create million of such images.

Аfter each, say, 10 thousands produce following steps (may be it is even better if one will write his observations in a notebook):

- move the mouse
- try to scroll any window opened with lengthy content
- minimize and maximize some windows

If those actions take longer and longer time after each iteration, than yes, it's look like implementor for some very unintuitive reasons treats each binary equivalent image like a separate chunk of data )